# Adding More than One Criteria to a Predicate List

Tags: c#, wpf, predicate

I have `Companies` that I am attempting to filter down using `criteria`. Each `Company` has a `CurrentStatus`, and the method to filter is called everytime the user checks a `CheckBox` to define a filter. I currently have this working almost exactly how I want it, aside from one thing. This is what I have;

```
    private void FilterCompanyType(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        criteria.Clear();

        if (currentCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<CompanyModel>(x => x.CurrentStatus == 1));
        }

        if (nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<CompanyModel>(x => x.CurrentStatus == 0));
        }

        foreach (CheckBox checkBox in companyFilters.Children)
        {
            if (!CheckCheckBoxes())
            {
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                compDetailsLabel.Content = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = CompanyICollectionView;
                CompanyICollectionView.Filter = dynamic_Filter;
                SetSelectedCompany(selectedIndex);
                dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said this is working OK, it works for when the user wants to see a list of `Companies` where `CurrentStaus == 1` OR a list of `Companies` where `CurrentStatus == 0`. However, currently the user cannot see a list of `Companies`, if both `CheckBoxes` are checked where `CurrentStatus == 0` AND `CurrentStatus == 1`.

I have tried adding this but it does not work with both `CheckBoxes` checked;

```
if (nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == true && currentCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    criteria.Add(new Predicate<CompanyModel>(x => x.CurrentStatus == 0));
    criteria.Add(new Predicate<CompanyModel>(x => x.CurrentStatus == 1));
}
```

This just returns an empty `DataGrid`. How can I change the `Predicate` to allow for both?

Comment: You can try `criteria.Add( new Predicate<CompanyModel>( x => ( x.CurrentStatus == 1 || x.CurrentStatus == 0 ) ) )` for the both is checked.

Comment: @bars222 unfortunately using this still results in no `Companies` being shown in the `DataGrid`

Comment: Also you should add code into previous `if` statements. if (currentCheckBox.IsChecked == true && nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == false)

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand, `if` statements should look like this.

```
if ( currentCheckBox.IsChecked == true && nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == false )
{
    criteria.Add( new Predicate<CompanyModel>( x => x.CurrentStatus == 1 ) );
}
else if ( nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == true && currentCheckBox.IsChecked == false )
{
    criteria.Add( new Predicate<CompanyModel>( x => x.CurrentStatus == 0 ) );
}
else if ( nonCurrentCheckBox.IsChecked == true && currentCheckBox.IsChecked == true )
{
    criteria.Add( new Predicate<CompanyModel>( x => ( x.CurrentStatus == 0 || x.CurrentStatus == 1 ) ) );
}
```